# Symfony 3 - set cache expire

Tags: php, symfony, caching

I have controller:

```
/**
 * Class ExampleController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 * @Cache(expire="tomorrow")
 */
class ExampleController extends Controller
```

How I can set cache expire to: `(new \DateTime("Y-m-d 03:14:00"))->modify("tomorrow")`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? You want to set the expire date to tomorrow, but in the annotation there's already tomorrow set.

Comment: So the expire should be at "03:14:00 of the next day"? If yes then you can just use `"tomorrow  03:14:00"`.

Comment: @vstm thanks!!!! :)